# How to redirect different users to their respective login pages when they log out?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created two users: User and Admin, and created two different guards for them. Also I've created two different login pages for each of the users. User login page is protected by default users guest middleware and Admin login page is protected by guest:admin middleware. For now, I've used the same logout page for both users and it redirects to Laravel's default '/' page. How do I redirect different users to their respective login pages depending on their guards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the `logout()` function inside

`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');  // <--instead of this
    }
```

You can do the following:

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
          $guard = 'admin';
        }
        else {
          $guard = 'web';
        }

        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        switch ($guard) {
           case 'admin':
             return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        break;

        default:
            return redirect('/login');
        break;
        }
    }
```

Of course here i am assuming that the guard for admins is named `admin` and also your route for `admin\login` is named `admin.login`, hope this helps.

Comment: once all guards are all flushed out.. is switch($guard) gonna work? Plus is it good idea to modify files inside vendor? thnx :)

Comment: My bad I didn't notice that, I was about to edit it actually, I have updated the answer and this should work, also from my honest opinion if you know what you're doing then it's fine to edit any thing anywhere, if you felt like something broke you can just roll back the changes and look for other workarounds :)

Comment: omartarek! thanks for your help.. It is surely gonna help me a lot. :)

Comment: Ooopppsss... 
ErrorException in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 156:
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::$guard

Comment: Sorry I took so long I was looking into it, since we can't access `protected` properties I wrote another workaround and edited the answer, of course you can modify this but this is the general idea, now hopefully everything should work :)

Comment: @Azima you may override this `logout()` method in loginController, so that you don't  have to edit the core files. because loginController uses  the trait  itself `use AuthenticatesUsers;`

Answer (score 0):

Override `logout()` method in loginContoller:

```
public function logout()
{
    if(auth()->user()->is_admin)
    {
       $this->guard()->logout();
       return redirect('adminLogin/');
    }
    else
    {
       $this->guard()->logout();
       return redirect('userLogin/');
    }

}
```

Comment: Override logout() method inside vendor folder?

Comment: @Azima in LoginController

Comment: thanks... :) But since I'm a newbie... where does this 'is_admin'  come from?

Comment: @Azima you need to make a DB field as is_admin set it to 1 if user is admin then make check as mentioned above in answer

Comment: @bluemoon ohh.. but I've used two separate tables for users and admins... is there someway around to go along with this?

Comment: yes dear you can use same approach also for admins table. hope so you have made a special field for admin so you can use a condition on that base @Azima

Comment: i think @Azima you got it what i want to say however if you still face difficulty you can discuss ...

Comment: @SanzeebAryal there are many solution to resolve your problem
1 before put the link logout on your webpage you need to check
if is User the logout link is http://yourwebsite.com/userlogout
if is Admin the   logout link  is http://yourwebsite.com/userlogout
2 User and Admin go to the Logout link is http://yourwebsite.com/logout
you need to check:
if user is admin --> logout and redirect to any where
else if user is user --> logout and redirect to any where
the code for logout and redirect is : 
Auth::logout();
return Redirect::to('login');//redirect to login page

Comment: @bluemoon It's pretty clear what you said dear.. but nothing is coming outta my thick rookie skull.. :D

Comment: @Azima. it may help if you could share your middlewares.

Comment: In AdminLoginController.php:
public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware('guest:admin');
 }

Comment: @bluemoon can you give me your fb Id or mail Id or something... so I can get interact with you better?

Comment: IMO you should store your redirection path in different user models. So logout can take specified one. E.g. Admin model has func. logoutPath(), User model logoutPath() etc. So you can only use redirect($user->logoutPath());